# can not call uber API from javascript, with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error

Tags: javascript, jquery, uber-api

I am trying to load info from the uber API using javascript on a web page.

Well, basically I am playing with [this tutorial](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/uber-api/#The-Complete-Project), but I am getting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` errors.

I have my `CLIENT ID` and `SERVER TOKEN`, and I left most of the other options blanked.

I tried to host it in the localhost and filled `http://localhost:8000` in the `ORIGIN URI` but with no luck.

For the page https://kylelam.github.io/final-section/, I tried filled in `https://*`, `https://kylelam.github.io`, and `https://kylelam.github.io/*`, with combination of with and without `dataType: 'jsonp',` but I am still having trouble figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: Did you set the **Origin URI** on the **Authentication** section of the Uber API page to http://localhost:8000? (no forward slash after url)

Comment: yea.. I tried that too.. no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this in meantime as workaround CORS issue

http://crossorigin.me/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, port numbers for localhost will not correctly show up in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, even after setting the Origin URI field for your app. This is a known issue that we hope to fix soon.